# Group in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have some issue in my sales report . I want to make a report like this, in which two columns are there..

**Team**                   **TotalSales**

**Team A**                     **1000**

**a1**                                                                  **500**

**a2**                                                     **500**

**Team B**                                                  **400**

**Team C**                                                   **800**

---

**Total**                                                      **2200**

here a1 and a2 are sub part of Team A.1000 is sum of a1 and a2 ToltSales.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Table Wizard - set your team name to the grouping field, and your values in the details field.  Enable totals lines and the layout you'd prefer.  The resulting table will be pretty close to what you need logic-wise, you'll just need to format it how you'd like.

I'd advise taking some time to look at how the wizard sets up grouping properties, as the wizard won't be useful at all when you need to get into very complicated tables with multiple levels of grouping.

Comment: Thank you kyzen, but my problem is different..When I do this TotalSales  of a1 and a2 it comes in  two times, one for tolat and other is value .Both are same...So I hide the Sum(TotalSales) if there is no sub part of Team...In this condition TotalSales will comes in second line , not infront of a1 and a2...How can do this that TotalSales will come infront of a1 and a2.